# Keyboard issues VMWare Workstation

Tags: keyboard, centos, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I have VMWare-Workstation 8.0.0 build-471780.
My host OS is Windows 7 Ultimate, SP1.
My guest OS is CentOS 6.0.
I have following keyboard issues:
1. When I press a key on guest OS (for example Enter) it repeats 2-10 times. It happens to all the keys. When I press a key very quickly - multiple enter doesn't occur.
2. At a random time guest OS stops receiving events from the keyboard. I was typing and at the next moment the keyboard just stopped working. The mouse was fine and all I could do - restart guest OS. And it happens all the time, the keyboard stops working at random moments.

I tried to find solution to the first issue. I have installed keyboard drivers - didn't help. I have also installed VMWare Tools 8.8.0, build 471268 - didn't help. I have also read an article from WMVare community that suggests to check if guest OS time is moving ahead of host OS - but it isn't.
How could I fix those solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to the issue 1: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=196